# already changed the field to string, but still got error

Tags: json, flutter, dart, model

why there is error on the *img attached. it says
-The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dartargument_type_not_assignable

[image]

Comment: Try restarting your vs code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take **json['id']** as an example. **json** is declared as Map<String,dynamic>, which means that **json['id']** is of type **dynamic**. You can not assign dynamic to **UserModel**'s field id, which is of type String.

You should cast json value before assigning it to String:

```dart
return UserModel(
  id: json['id'] as String,
...
)
```

Same applies to other fields.

Comment: "You can not assign dynamic to UserModel's field id, which is of type String." This depends on the linter rules the OP is using, which we don't know.

Comment: Alex answer is correct, UserModel has it owns rules. If id is String, json['id'] should cast as String. Reading values from Map that explicit is dynamic, you have to explicit tell what type is the value if the model is not dynamic.